# debugging faild "cant find the process issue"

Tags: debugging, testing, adb

I'm having an issue with the debugging process while testing the Android application I created on Android Studio. When I click on "run" in Android Studio, the application successfully install and opens on my phone. However, when I click on "debug", the application is installed successfully but fails to open. A message appears on my phone saying "waiting for debugger to attach", then a message appears in Android Studio saying "fail to find the process com...." and the debugging process fails. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

I have tried several troubleshooting methods to resolve my issue. Firstly, I attempted to kill and start the ADB server. Additionally, I cleared the cache of Android Studio and restarted the software. I also tried using a virtual device with Android version 5.1 and physical devices with Android version 12. Moreover, I restarted my device and relaunched Android Studio to see if it resolved the issue.
BUT nothing work

Comment: I also tried another project and faced the same problem and tried usb cable and wifi and it the same

Comment: Is the shown package name in the error message correct? Also check the actual package name of the app that has been installed. Android Studio may have a bug which confuses the package name some times.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your comment but it's the same package name in my phone and in error message but I have noticed that I cannot find any files associated with the package name of my app in the internal memory/Android/data folder, unlike other apps on my phone. Is that make any difference ? my app works well despite this.

Comment: That folder is the external storage of the app, using it is optional. Most apps only use the app private storage. As your app is a development app you can use Android Studio Device Explorer to browse into your app's private directories in `/data/data/your_app_packagename_...` and se the app private files which are not accessible for regular apps on unrooted devices.

Comment: @Robert thank u again I have followed the steps you suggested, and I can confirm that the package name on my phone is the same as the one in the error message. Could there be any other possible causes for the issue I am experiencing?